# Hadoop Logs Data set

Tags: logging, hadoop, mapreduce, dataset

I am just wondering if there is a data set for different Hadoop jobs logs. The data set may have logs for different Hadoop jobs using different machines hardware configurations and different Hadoop configurations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hadoop data set can be found here.**
[The is the link of github for different datasets including hadoop](https://github.com/logpai/loghub/tree/master/Hadoop)